# Function inside a function, access previous environment

Tags: r

I am trying to access a data frame created within a function and use its environment to access some data. I know the ideal is to call it as an input in the function, but I am trying to avoid it, so I don't have to list hundreds of inputs. Any help or resources are appreciated.

An example is below:

```
library(dplyr)

data_v1 <- tribble(~var1, ~var2,
                    1, 2)

postprocess_data <- function(){
  
  data_v3 <- data_v2 %>% 
    mutate(var2 = var2*3)
  
  data_v3
}


process_data <- function(){
  
  data_v2 <- data_v1 %>% 
    mutate(var1 = var1*3)
  
  data_v3_inside <- postprocess_data()
  
  data_v3_inside
    
}

process_data()
```

Comment: Why can't the data object name passed into the function?

Answer (score 2):

We can get the object from the `parent.frame`

```
postprocess_data <- function(){
  
  data_v2 <- get("data_v2", envir = parent.frame())
  data_v3 <- data_v2 %>% 
    mutate(var2 = var2*3)
  
  data_v3
}


process_data <- function(){
  
  data_v2 <- data_v1 %>% 
    mutate(var1 = var1*3)
  
  data_v3_inside <- postprocess_data()
  
  data_v3_inside
    
}
```

-testing

```
process_data()
# A tibble: 1 × 2
   var1  var2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     6
```

Comment: This works, but it's a bad design.  Since `postprocess_data` is defined at the top level, it can be called by any function, but it will only work if it is called by `process_data`.

Comment: I think that can be addressed by simply making the environment an argument: `postprocess_data <- function(envir = parent.frame()) {
  
  data_v2 <- get("data_v2", envir = envir);
  data_v3 <- data_v2 %>% 
    mutate(var2 = var2*3);
  
  data_v3
}`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck:  that has the identical problem.  You can still see `postprocess_data` from anywhere, but it will only work if `process_data` is the caller.

Comment: that isn't true. It can be used from anywhere and it is up to the caller to provide the appropriate `envir` that contains the relevant object.  That is no different than any other function which requires that you give it appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Your title describes the right way to do this.

Since `process_data` only needs to access `data_v1`, it's fine as it is (though it would be better style if `data_v1` was an argument).

But `postprocess_data` needs access to `data_v2`, a local variable in `process_data`.  So the ideal design is to define `postprocess_data` inside `process_data`.  Then it will be able to see all of the variables that are local to `process_data`, as well as all global variables.  For example,

```r
library(dplyr)

data_v1 <- tribble(~var1, ~var2,
                    1, 2)


process_data <- function(){

  postprocess_data <- function(){
  
    data_v3 <- data_v2 %>% 
      mutate(var2 = var2*3)
  
    data_v3
  }


  data_v2 <- data_v1 %>% 
    mutate(var1 = var1*3)
  
  data_v3_inside <- postprocess_data()
  
  data_v3_inside
    
}

process_data()
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>    var1  var2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3     6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Edited to add:  There's one slightly risky thing in the way I wrote the code here.

If you ever modified `process_data()` so that it called `postprocess_data()` before creating `data_v2`, then the nested function would not find it in the enclosing environment, and would keep looking for it in the global environment.  If it happened to find a copy there you might end up with a subtle bug that caused you trouble.

So a good idea is to create any variable used by the nested function very early, e.g. setting `data_v2 <- NULL` before the definition of `postprocess_data`.  The `NULL` value should trigger an error if you haven't replaced it at the time you call the nested function.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!, It is a nice solution. but this is a large project, and creating the function inside is not ideal for documenting purposes.

Comment: It's always a good idea to keep things simple.   If both functions are big, then pass the data as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Assuming that you have control over and can modify `process_data` insert this as the first line of the body.  That will make a copy of `postprocess_data` except its environment will be the frame within the running `process_data` so that any free variables in `postprocess_data` will be looked up there.

```
environment(postprocess_data) <- environment()
```

**2)** If you don't have control over `process_data` and cannot change it but do have control over `postprocess_data` replace it with this.

```
  postprocess_data <- function(envir = parent.frame()) with(envir, {       
    data_v3 <- data_v2 %>% 
      mutate(var2 = var2*3)
  
    data_v3
  })
```

**2a)** or with this which makes it act sort of like a macro.

```
  postprocess_data <- function(envir = parent.frame()) eval(substitute({
  
    data_v3 <- data_v2 %>% 
      mutate(var2 = var2*3)
  
    data_v3
  }), envir = envir)
```